# Check if a number contains digits A and B. Prolog

Tags: prolog

```
contains_digits(0,_,_,_,_):-
  !.
contains_digits(N,A,B,A1,B1):-

  % if the last digit of the number is equals to a digit A,
  % then flag A1 is set to 1, and if a digit B was founded then exit recursion.
  N2 is N mod 10, N2 =:= A, A1 is 1, B1 =:= 0;

  % here is the same like above, but for a digit B.
  N2 is N mod 10, N2 =:= B, B1 is 1, A1 =:= 0;

  % take the number N without the last digit. 12345 -> 1234 -> 123 -> ... -> 1
  N1 is N div 10,
  contains_digits(N1,A,B,A1,B1),

  % if both digits has been found, then return true, else return false.
  A1 is 1, B1 is 1.
```

I call it like this:

```
?- contains_digits(123456,3,9,0,0).
```

But this code doesn't work, because I don't know how to declare flags `A1` and `B1` correctly. In this code it returns `false` when I try to `A1 is 1` or `B1 is 1`, because of `A1 = 0` and `B1 = 0`, and I don't know how to change them to `1`.

**I did it as follows and it works properly.**

```
read_digits(A,B):-
  write("Number A: "),
  read(A), nl,
  write("Number B: "),
  read(B), nl.

contains(0,_):-
  !.

contains(N,X):-
  N2 is N mod 10,
  X \= N2,
  N1 is N div 10,
  contains(N1,X).

foo(N):-
  read_digits(A,B),
  not(contains(N,A)),
  not(contains(N,B)).
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution [based on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701991/split-a-number-into-a-list-of-digits-in-prolog):

```
contains(Number,A,B):-
    number_codes(Number,N), 
    maplist(plus(48),X,N),    
    member(A,X),
    member(B,X).

?- contains(123456,1,3).
true ;
false
```

You can use also `memberchk/2` if you don't want also the false solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that builds on **damianodamiano**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59725006/381744) using [builtin](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=builtin) predicates:

```
contains_digits(Number,Digit1,Digit2) :-                                        
    between(0,inf,Number),                                                      
    between(0,9,Digit1),                                                        
    between(0,9,Digit2),                                                        
    atom_number(Char1,Digit1),                                                  
    atom_number(Char2,Digit2),                                                  
    number_chars(Number,Chars),                                                 
    member(Char1,Chars),                                                        
    member(Char2,Chars).
```

You can use `memberchk/2` instead of `member/2`. The important point is that `contains_digits/3` has the following [specification](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=modes):

```
contains_digits(?Number,?Digit1,?Digit2) is nondet.
```

For example:

```
?- contains_digits(N,D1,D2).
% succeeds with all solutions for N, D1 and D2.

?- findall((N,M),contains_digits(123,N,M),Sols).
Sols = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)].

?- findall(N,contains_digits(123,N,2),Sols).
Sols = [1, 2, 3].

?- findall(N,contains_digits(123,1,N),Sols).
Sols = [1, 2, 3].

?- contains_digits(123,1,2).
true ;
false.

?- contains_digits(123,1,5).
false.

?- contains_digits(123,5,1).
false.

?- contains_digits(123,5,8).
false.
```

This solution sacrifices semideterminism for the abilitiy to generate solutions for arbitrarily instantiated numbers and digits. More sophisticated approaches would use the [CLP(FD)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd) library or [DCG](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=DCG)'s to generate candidate solutions efficiently. That is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: I'd like to understand how to do it at a lower level of abstraction.

Comment: @eugene987: Prolog does not encourage lower levels of abstraction.